# Passing values between popup windows in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

I have a page created in ASP.NET with a button in it.
What I would like to achieve is, 
 On Clicking on the button, a popup (popup 1) window will be displayed with a Label and three buttons.
 On clicking on one of the button, Another popup (popup 2) window will be displayed with a textbox and submit button.
 On giving a text and clicking on the submit button (from popup 2), the text should be displayed in the place of the label in popup 1.

And also please advice me how about having a list of elements (may be 10 table row values) be processed and sent back to popup 1 from popup 2?

Is this possible? If Yes, Please advise me how.

Comment: Hi @giri, you could use the jQuery dialog box and pass variable back and forth in javascript. Have a look at the documentation here: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Step 1: Create a popup with okcontrol and cancel control and one more button to trigger another popup.
Step 2: Create the second popup with cancel control and another button (click event) to send the values to the previous popup.
Step 3: On the click event of the button in second popup, update the values in the first popup and hide the popup.

This will show the content in popup 1 sent from the second popup.

This worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways

1.By writing handler code for the popup2 
like this

```
popup1textbox.text=popup2textbox.text;
popup1.show();
```

2.By calling a javascript in the button onclick event of popup2

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function btnSubmit_Click() {
         document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value=document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value
        }
    </script>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                OnClientClick="return btnSubmit_Click();" />
```

Comment: when you click on the submit button to finish editing in the popup 2, both the popup will be closed and the page needs to refresh to see the update.  and also, on clicking on the "OK" button from popup 2 is for okcontrol of the popup. This cannot help me to achieve my target.